# Type Mismatch When Sorting with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I am trying to implement VBA code that automatically sorts a range of data dependent on the text in column L but I receive a type mismatch error. I am not sure where I have gone wrong. Here is my code:

```
Dim AccuracySortRow
AccuracySortRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
With ActiveSheet
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("L8:L" & AccuracySortRow), _
                        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                        CustomOrder:="ENTRY DENIED, ENTRY GRANTED", _
                        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .Sort.SetRange ("B8:L" & AccuracySortRow)
    .Sort.Header = xlNo
    .Sort.MatchCase = False
    .Sort.Apply
End With
```

I specified the final row in the range that I want to sort because there is another set of data under this range that I do not want to interfere with.

Comment: Which line gives the error? Also, you give the range as L8:L in Range then as B8:L in setRange

Comment: *there is another set of data under this range that I do not want to interfere with* - so, the `AccuracySortRow` is in that other set of data, no? `Rows.Count` is at the very bottom of the sheet; going `.End(xlUp)` on that would bring you to the last populated row in column L, which presumably is in the "bottom data set". Are these `ListObject` tables? If so, skip the "find last row" part and use the `DataBodyRange` for the `ListColumn` you want to use as a key. If not... well now would be a good time to hit Ctrl+T on these "not-table" ranges-that-should-be-tables.

Comment: Place a breakpoint (F9) on `With ActiveSheet`, run the code; what's the value of `AccuracySortRow`? Note that this variable should be declared `As Long` (currently an implicit `Variant`), and that the unqualified `Cells` call (and `Row` too, but that's not impactful) is also implicitly referring to `ActiveSheet`, so in theory that assignment also belongs in the `With` block scope.

Comment: I'm not sure which line causes the error as when the error appears, there is no option to debug. The dataset that is below only runs to column H, so I thought that setting to count AccuracySortRow to count to column L would exclude the other data set.They are not ListObject tables

Comment: `.Sort.SetRange ("B8:L" & AccuracySortRow)` is passing a `String` expression (drop the parentheses, they're redundant) to a method [that is expecting a `Range` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sort.setrange), hence the type mismatch.

Comment: Mathieu, when placing a break on With ActiveSheet, I get a message that says "Cannot enter break mode at this time"

Comment: That is rather unexpected. What procedure is this code written in / how is it invoked?

Comment: The code is invoked by clicking an ActiveX button

Comment: So this is a `CommandButton1_Click` handler procedure then - there's no reason for it to refuse to hit a breakpoint... can you break on `AccuracySortRow = ...`? Or do `Debug.Print AccuracySortRow` immediately after assigning it - then you can see the row number in the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G) - is it as expected? I'm pretty sure the row number is at the bottom of the 2nd data set.

Answer (score 1):

Add the custom order as an array to the CustomListCount then use that as the OrderCustom argument.

```
Option Explicit

Sub customsortL()

    'add the custom order to the CustomListCount
    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Array("ENTRY DENIED", "ENTRY GRANTED")

    With Worksheets("sheet11")
        With .Range(.Cells(8, "L"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp))

            .Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                  Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo, MatchCase:=False, _
                  OrderCustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1

        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The *type mismatch* is most likely occurring here:

```
.Sort.SetRange ("B8:L" & AccuracySortRow)
```

Because the expression `("B8:L" & AccuracySortRow)` resolves to a `String`, and [`Sort.SetRange` expects a `Range` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sort.setrange). Note that `.Sort.SetRange (someRangeObject)` will also throw a type mismatch error, because these parentheses are forcing the expression to be evaluated *before* the result is passed to the method, so that would be passing a 2D `Variant` array (via implicit default member call on `Range.[_Default]`, which resolves to `Range.Value` in this context), which is still not a `Range` object: drop the parentheses.

Additionally, I suspect the value of `AccuracySortRow` is such that you're encompassing this "other data" you don't want to interfere with - assuming column L contains data in both data sets.

Assuming column L contains no blanks, you need to use `.End(xlDown)` from the top (well, from row 8 I guess), not `.End(xlUp)` from the bottom, if you want to end up with a row number that's in the top data set. All of this would be much easier to do if the range to be sorted was a `ListObject` / table (note that `.Sort.SetRange` can't be used with a table).

Comment: The second data set does not contain any values in column L, it only runs as far as column H. After dropping the parenthesis I still get a type mismatch. What I am trying to do is sort each row in B8:L based on what the text is in column L

Comment: Dropping the parens will still pass a `String`. It needs to be a `Range`.

Comment: In my case I had change my setRange call to workbook.Sheets("Sheet").Sort.SetRange(CType(xlTbDev.UsedRange, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range))

Comment: @Jack that's because you're using COM interop in .NET; the question was tagged [vba], so the code *is* COM. Note that `workbook.Sheets` returns an `object` so that makes the chained `.Sort` call late-bound - `Option Strict On` would prevent implicit late binding and help prevent such errors.